# Ajax Code to run PHP query After Facebook Like Button is Clicked

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook-like

I have the PHP below on a file called fblike.php.  On another file, I have the Facebook Like button.  The Like button functions.  I would like to run the code below when the Facebook Like button is clicked.

I know that `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {}` is supposed to run whenever the Like button is clicked.  I know that I am probably supposed to use Javascript and maybe Ajax to cause the PHP on fblike.php to run.

But after multiple tries, I can't get it to work.  What is the specific Ajax code that I could include within the Facebook Event?  Do I need to do anything to the Like button code to allow the Facebook Event to work?

```
$submissionid = $_POST['submissionid'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];

mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());




$q = "INSERT INTO fblikes VALUES (NULL, '$submissionid', '$uid', NULL)";

$r = mysql_query($q);

if($r) 
    {

    echo "Success!";
    }
elseif(!$r) 
    {
    echo "Failed!";
    }
```

Comment: mysql_query ? O__O oh wait I use it too

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "path/to/yourscript.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send("submissionid="+response.submissionid+"&uid="+response.uid); 
});
```

Essentially, you'd have to pull the variables out of the response and send them via a POST-method AJAX request to your PHP script.

You can optionally expand the function() to check for success:

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText == "Success!")
```

Comment: Okay... on the file with the Like button, I have $uid and $submission as PHP variables.  How could I integrate them into the xmlhttp.send you have here?

Comment: I think one of us might misunderstand; are the UID and SubmissionID variables incoming for your script, or do you generate them? Because if you generate them, I don't see how're they connected to the `FB.Event`. If you receive them, then I assume that they're coming from the Facebook like event, and exist somewhere in the `response` object.

Comment: They're on the page with the Like button, and if someone clicks the Like button I would like to use them to run the query above.  the FB.event is what Facebook provides to track Like clicks.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by response object.

Comment: Ok, so they are incoming. My guess is that all of that information is tucked away in that `response` object. Try `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', console.log(response));`, and check to console to see what information is available through the object.

Comment: Okay, I added `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', console.log(response));` but I'm not sure where to go now to see the console.

Comment: What browser are you accessing this in? :)

Comment: Fantastic. Right-click on the like button and click "Inspect Element". You'll see a new window with a set of buttons [Elements, Resources, Network, ..., Console]. Click Console, then your like button.

Comment: Okay... when I click "console", it just some info on the Google AdSense I'm running but nothing about the Facebook Like button...

Comment: Even after clicking your like button? Because that means that the FB.Event is not returning any information, which suggests you have the button set up incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, after I clicked the Like, "Console" says `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` then my site, then `from frame with URL` then what looks like Facebook linking back to my site.

Comment: Looks like the button has been set up incorrectly (at least a little bit). I would check both it's linking URL, and it's redirect URL and make sure that they're both globally accessible (i.e. http://public.url)